# IF statement with increment, and display value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to increment the value from `id="wordcount"` and add the value with existing value in `id="running-summary-total`. As you increase the value in id="wordcountl" also increment the value `id="running-summary-total"` and add and display the value in `id="running-summary-total"`

```
<div>
    <strong class="fa fa-dollar-sign">$</strong>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="" id="running-summary-total" value="0.00">
</div>
```

```
<input class="form-control input-number" type="number" name="wordcount" value="" min="1" max="100000000000" id="wordcount">
```

**Script**

```
 var z = document.getElementById("wordcount").value;
    console.log(z)
    if (++z) {
     var d = 30;
     var wc = d + 4;
   document.getElementById("running-summary-total").value =  +wc;
}
```

I don't know where I made a mistake, because the script is not working

Comment: Explain "it's not working". Did you checked for errors in console? It does something different from what you expect or it simple don't do nothing?

Comment: What is `d` here?

Comment: I guess you need to convert z to integer smth like   /// var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("wordcount").value);

Comment: There's a few strange things here. First, `d` variable doesn't exists (at least in your example). Second, what is `= +wc` in the last line?

Comment: sorry guys, ```var d = 30 ```

Comment: ```+wc ``` is the value you get from ``` var wc = d + 4;```

Comment: _When_ are you executing this? (Please show a proper [mre] of your issue, instead of mere snippets that lack context.) If you want this to do something when the value in #wordcount gets modified by the user, then you need to execute this via a change or input event handler.

Comment: What do you expect `if (++z)` to do? It increases `z` and enters the `if` when the result is non-zero. Then you ignore it

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to edit a `readonly` input, you first need to remove the readonly attribute before you can make any changes.

The question itself is quite unclear, what's `d` for instance?

This is the gist of how you would change it. Comment below with clarifications please and I can update it for you.

```
function changeReadonlyInput(inpt) {
  console.log("new Value " + inpt.value);
  var total = document.getElementById("running-summary-total");
  total.readonly = false;
  var d = 30;
  var wc = d + 4;
  total.value = inpt.value + wc;
  total.readonly = true;
}
```

Then attach that function to the eventlistener `oninput` on your `<input>` as shown below.

Demo

```js
function changeReadonlyInput(inpt) {
  console.log("new Value " + inpt.value);
  var total = document.getElementById("running-summary-total");
  total.readonly = false;
  var d = 30;
  var wc = d + 4;
  total.value = inpt.value + wc;
  total.readonly = true;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <strong class="fa fa-dollar-sign">$</strong>
  <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="" id="running-summary-total" value="0.00">
</div>

<input class="form-control input-number" type="number" name="wordcount" value="" min="1" max="100000000000" id="wordcount" oninput="changeReadonlyInput(this)">
```